# How to convert XGBoost model SHAP values from log odds to probabilities?

Tags: python, xgboost, shap

I trained an XGBoost Classifier and am trying to generate SHAP contributions in probabilities. I understand the output of shap.TreeExplainer for XGBoost models is in log odds ratios. I expect the expected_value of  explainer to be equal or close to the average predicted value in the dataset. However, I get exptected_value of -2.7776 (`explainer.expected_value`), which corresponds to probability of 0.0585 (`expit(-2.7776)`). This is significantlty lower compared to average predicted score of 0.21. Is there any step I am missing in converting expected value to probability?

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import shap
from scipy.special import expit

# Generate data 
X, Y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, 
                           n_features=20, 
                           n_redundant=0,  
                           n_classes=2, 
                           random_state=17, 
                           weights = [0.8, 0.2])

# Split into train and test 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1, random_state=7)

# Data check
print('Target rate: {:.0%}'.format(sum(Y)/len(Y)))
print('Target rate in train dataset: {:.0%}'.format(sum(y_train)/len(y_train)))
print('Target rate in test dataset: {:.0%}'.format(sum(y_test)/len(y_test)))

print('Total observations: {:.0f}'.format(len(X)))
print('Train observations: {:.0f}'.format(len(x_train)))
print('Test observations: {:.0f}'.format(len(x_test)))

# Train XGBoost model
model = GradientBoostingClassifier(
                          n_estimators = 50,
                          max_depth = 3,
                          random_state = 17
                         )

model.fit(x_train, y_train)


# Get accuracy score and confusion matrix for train and test datasets
# There doesn't seem to be issues with model performance, it is pretty close for train and test datasets
acc_train = model.score(x_train, y_train)
acc_test = model.score(x_test, y_test)
cm_train = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred_class_train, normalize = 'true')
cl_report_train = classification_report(y_train, y_pred_class_train)
cm_test = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_class_test, normalize = 'true')
cl_report_test = classification_report(y_test, y_pred_class_test)

# Print results
print('MODEL ACCURACY:\n \
    training data: {:.2%}\n \
    test data: {:.2%}'.format(acc_train, acc_test))

print('\nCONFUSION MATRIX (train data):\n {}'.format(cm_train.round(3)))
print('\nCLASSIFICATION REPORT (train data):\n {}'.format(cl_report_train))

print('\nCONFUSION MATRIX (test data):\n {}'.format(cm_test.round(3)))
print('\nCLASSIFICATION REPORT (test data):\n {}'.format(cl_report_test))

# Check average predicted score 
# Train
y_pred_prob_train = model.predict_proba(x_train)
y_pred_class_train = model.predict(x_train)
print('Train: Average predicted score: {:.2%}'.format(np.mean(y_pred_prob_train[:,1])))

# Test
y_pred_prob_test = model.predict_proba(x_test)
y_pred_class_test = model.predict(x_test)
print('Test: Average predicted score: {:.2%}'.format(np.mean(y_pred_prob_test[:,1])))

# Get SHAP values in log odds for test dataset
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x_test)

# Check SHAP expected value
print('SHAP expected value: {:.4f}'.format(explainer.expected_value[0]))    
print('SHAP expected value transformed: {:.4f}'.format(expit(explainer.expected_value[0])))    
print('Average predicted value: {:.4f}'.format(np.mean(y_pred_prob_test[:,1])))   
# Average predicted value is ~ 0.21 while shap expected value only ~ 0.06.
```

Comment: It may just be that expit is non-linear.  In the rare-instance case especially, where the logit is convex, the average probability will generally be larger than the probability corresponding to the average log-odds.  (But I'm also surprised by the size of the difference.)  See also https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/963#issuecomment-569348682